# I have to click twice to activate function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, fadeout

I am having a lot of trouble with jQuery. I have to click twice on a button to make the page disappear. I have tried importing both versions of jQuery and I tried to use the fadeOut() function on different elements, but nothing has prevailed. It works the second time I click, but never the first. This is a recurring problem, and I need to know how it can be fixed. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>CSS3 Buttons Showcase</h1>
    <a href="#" id="btn-1" onclick="fadeBg()">Click Me!</a>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function fadeBg(){
            $("#btn-1").click(function(){
                $("body").fadeOut(1000);
            })
        }
```

Comment: We will need to see some code in order to help!

Comment: My guess, waiting for the code : rookie mistake. You are probably initializing the `click()` function inside another `click()` or something.

Comment: or the missing `$(document).ready`-handler

Comment: @JeremyThille How do you know? ;-)

Comment: as pointed out above, "fadeBg()" should contain solely " $("body").fadeOut(1000);"

Comment: Annnnnd obviously, that was a rookie mistake, initializing a click inside another click :) How did I do that????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change your function to:

```
function fadeBg(){          
      $("body").fadeOut(1000);    
}
```

In your HTML code `onclick` is being set to run your function `fadeBg`. So in your function you must put what you want to run; in this case `$("body").fadeOut(1000);`

Comment: The answer was Jeremy Thille's... ;-)

Comment: @Veverke my apologise, I don't see the comment when I load the page there was only first comment.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It took me unreasonably long to see my mistake. I will avoid it in the future. Thank you to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're not binding the jQuery event handler until the `fadeBg()` function is called on the first click. Try this instead:

```
<h1>CSS3 Buttons Showcase</h1>
<a href="#" id="btn-1">Click Me!</a>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $("#btn-1").click(function(){
        $("body").fadeOut(1000);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to bind a click to an element :

**1. The old dirty inline javascript (avoid)**

```
(HTML) : <button onclick="doSomething()">
```

and **2. the cleaner event binding**

```
(HTML) : <button id="myButton">

(JS) : $('#myButton').click( doSometing )
```

You mixed both, binding two clicks on the same element.

```
<button onclick="doSomething()">

function doSomething(){ // will be done on first click
  $('#myButton').click( doSometingElse ) // will be done on second click
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the same action twice, the code is:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>CSS3 Buttons Showcase</h1>
    <a href="#" id="btn-1">Click Me!</a>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#btn-1").click(function(){
                $("body").fadeOut(1000);
            })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fadeBg(){
            $("#btn-1").click(function(){
                $("body").fadeOut(1000);
            })
        }
```

You added the onclick event directly in your html. This function adds a second event to the same button.

Just remove the onclick event in your element And do this:

```
$("#btn-1").click(function(){
                    $("body").fadeOut(1000);
                })
```

It's considered bad practice adding onclick events directly in your html element. You can but it doesn't look good.